# Adding callbacks to lightgbm in r

Tags: r, machine-learning, lightgbm

How do I add lightgbms callbacks in R. Seems I am having a naming problem and I can't figure out the exact names to use like for "lgb.cb.print.evaluation" callback in R
Here's my attempt at it

```
m_gbm <- lgb.train(params, xtrain, 600, list(val = xval), eval_freq = 10, early_stopping_rounds = 25, verbose = 1, callbacks=list(lgb.cb.print.evaluation(period=1, show_stdv=True)))
```

This fails because lgb.cb.print.evaluation is not the correct name for the callback  as told by the error:

> Error in lgb.cb.print.evaluation(period = 1, show_stdv = True): could not find function "lgb.cb.print.evaluation"

Can anyone please provide me with a usage example of this?

The source code for callbacks is in https://github.com/Microsoft/LightGBM/blob/master/R-package/R/callback.R

Comment: Have you checked the documentation.  Please include the package name.  Are you using [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/LightGBM/tree/master/R-package) package?

Comment: yes I am using the mentioned package

Comment: you can use the argument `eval_freq = 1` for print verbose at each iteration.